# Drawing One Element per Second

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a List and I want to iterate through the list and draw an element every second.  I trying to use the canvas element's AddChild routine.  This is sort of what I'm doing; I've tried a Background worker and the Dispatcher.Invoke to attempt to resolve the threading issues but with no luck:

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
   protected void OnMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
   {
     List<UIElement> elements = GetElements();

     Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
     this.AddChild(canvas);

     foreach (var k in elements)
     {
        canvas.Children.Add(k);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
   }
}
```

I'm basically trying to sort of draw a slideshow with shapes, but it locks up on this line: `this.AddChild(canvas)`.  I'm obviously doing something wrong with the threading, but I can't figure it out.

How do I modify my code to render one shape every second to a window.  I'd like to eventually clear the previous shape before drawing the next one, but that can come later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx):

```
List<UIElement> elements = GetElements();

Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
this.AddChild(canvas);

var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

bw.DoWork += ( sender, e ) =>
{
  foreach (var k in elements)
  {
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( new Action( () => canvas.Children.Add( k ) ) );
     Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
  }
};

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```